# TOUCH_TAP triggered by TOUCH_END

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, event-handling, touch-event

The title says it all. I have both events registered for the same object. It is meant to differentiate a drag from a tap, but when `TOUCH_END` fires, so does `TOUCH_TAP`. This represents a problem if my program cannot differentiate between the two. I have tried unregistering the `TOUCH_TAP` handler inside of `TOUCH_BEGIN` and reregistering for `TOUCH_END` but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

How can I differentiate between a drag and a tap? My target SDK is AIR 4.0 for iOS.

Comment: I'm not familiar to AS but an easy way to differentiate drag and tap is to simply intercept the touch distance (delta) I presume. Can you use that?

Comment: @AyanSengupta Good idea, but it seems hackish and "There Must Be A Better Way!"

Comment: Yeah I know, but this is the best I could offer you, within my limitations ;)

Comment: I will wait a while longer to see if anybody can post a proper solution before testing your implementation, and see if I can make it feel smooth to use.